Why Piccolo doesnt remember his original planet, if he fused with Kamisama and has his memories?
In Dragon Ball Z, Piccolo fused with Kamisama and got his memories. After leaving the The Sanctuary of Kami-sama right after he fused, he called Popo his friend and before he fused Kamisama told him, he would get his knowledge.
Now in Dragon Ball Daima Piccolo is asked by Bulma if he missed his own planet now that he's there, but Piccolo tells her that it was his father King Piccolo who lived there and not him. But it was actually the fusion of King Piccolo and Kamisama who lived there, and since he's fused with Kamisama he should have memories of that planet
Why Piccolo doesnt remember his original planet, if he fused with Kamisama and has his memories?

I don't know the exact phrasing, but could it not be that he remembers the Nameless Namekian (on a side note, why not Nail, for that matter?) living there, but not himself, and therefore he has no longing for that place.
